# EditForm with data from Database Blazor Server app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor-server-side

I have a survey with questions and answers that saved in a database, when rendering it as a form in balzor server app with EditForm component so that end user can answer it. I face a problem when selecting an answer it affect all choices of other questions and I know why (because @bind-value to the same property of the viewModel).

Here is a snapshot of the code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aLht.png)

and this how it result when select an answer:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbOFd.png)

does anyone has faced senario before? or have an idea how can I implement this.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: radio buttons are grouped by name in HTML.  You have not provided any unique Name for your `InputRadioGroup`

Comment: That is right @Bennyboy1973, but how can i bind the values of each one into a list? Is that even possible  with blazor or i have to use js for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Blazor uses C#, you can avoid a lot of the problems with pure HTML, like having to use a string for a value in your radio buttons.  Instead, you can use an event like `@onclick` to directly set values.  Note that EditForm is used for handling validation-- but you don't really need any validation on a multiple choice survey question, so I just used normal html to make it simpler.

```
@foreach (var question in SurveyQuestions)
{
    <div>@question.QuestionText</div>
    @foreach (var item in question.items)
    {
        <input @onclick="()=>question.SelectedItem=item" type="radio" name="@("Q" + question.ID)" />@(item.value+"  ")
    }
    <br /><br />
}
<hr />
@foreach (var question in SurveyQuestions)
{
    if (question.SelectedItem is null)
    {
        <div>No answer has been selected for question @question.ID</div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div>The selected answer for Question @question.ID is @question.SelectedItem.value</div>
    }
    
}

@code {
    class RadioItem{ public int ID; public string value; }
    class RadioQuestion { public int ID; public string QuestionText;  public List<RadioItem> items = new(); public RadioItem? SelectedItem; }

    List<RadioQuestion> SurveyQuestions = new()
    {
        new RadioQuestion()
        {
            ID = 3,
            QuestionText = "Favorite City?",
             items = new List<RadioItem>()
             {
                 new RadioItem(){ID = 1, value = "Paris"},
                 new RadioItem(){ID = 2, value = "Cairo"},
                 new RadioItem(){ID = 3, value = "Vancouver" }
             }
        },
         new RadioQuestion()
        {
            ID = 2,
            QuestionText = "Favorite Food?",
             items = new List<RadioItem>()
             {
                 new RadioItem(){ID = 1, value = "Donair"},
                 new RadioItem(){ID = 2, value = "Bagel"},
                 new RadioItem(){ID = 3, value = "Burrito" }
             }
        },
    };
}
```